# Get my session id and Access token using curl php

Tags: rest-api

I want to get my current session id and Access token in salesforce ,  Im using curl with php  how to  I get,

i Dont know how to get it ,,,

if anyone Knows tell me

Thanks ,
Ganesh

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to accomplish that would be with the REST API using SessionID Authorization (as opposed to Oauth).

To do this, first you need to create a "Connected App" in your salesforce instance. You can do that here: https://login.salesforce.com/app/mgmt/forceconnectedapps/forceAppEdit.apexp.

Then once you've got your connected app setup, you'll want to copy the consumer_key and consumer_secret that Salesforce generates for you and use it in the following curl command:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=your_consumer_key" -d "client_secret=your_consumer_secret" -d "username=your_username" -d "password=your_password_plus_security_token"
```

If all goes well, you'll get back a response that looks something like this:

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D000000000abCDEF/00500000000gHIJQK2","issued_at":"1375515717557","instance_url":"https://na1.salesforce.com","signature":"X26l4MggO2go16d6bXo+YHhWUN+LWLSnwzc/0ap0x3A=","access_token":"00D000000000abCDEF!AQEAGJwlyvPbNQtRkLv1vDUIwkGaaG4l9oiQMeVNnopHcuDOrGkAT59s1c_zdlLNd_itHXZZai_Bq4L.uVqIjpJMHeiBzQF2"}
```

where "access_token" is your sessionId

You can find more information here under the heading "Session ID Authorization": http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/quickstart_oauth.htm

Comment: thanks , but in that curl i wont give any username and password , how to get session id or access token,

Comment: How are you authenticating, then?

Comment: Im using curl in php to assign url in localhost php server , i dont mention username and password , only i mention in that url consumer key & consumer secert value , then its atomatically login to my salesforce page , and get session id using httppost method in php

Comment: So you are getting your session id, then? I'm afraid I'm not following what your issue is.

Comment: I was given a consumer id and secret and naturally my colleague doesn't want to give me his password....am I basically screwed then?  how can I use the api by someone generating something and giving it to me so I can start programming?

Comment: Do you have your own username and password? Or can you have one created for you?